# Раскрасить самый высокий бар в нужный цвет

Tags: python, matplotlib

Отрисовываю барплоты циклом, хочу, чтоб автоматически в каждом рисунке определялся самый высокий бар и расскрашивался, например, в красный (чтоб прям сразу в глаза бросалось, какой из выборов был наиболее предпочитаемым). Скажите, пожалуйста, есть ли кратчайшие способы?

```
def autolabel(rects, labels=None, height_factor=1.01):
    for i, rect in enumerate(rects):
        height = rect.get_height()
        if labels is not None:
            try:
                label = labels[i]
            except (TypeError, KeyError):
                label = ' '
        else:
            label = '%d' % int(height)
        ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., height_factor*height,
                '{}'.format(label),
                ha='center', va='bottom')

for index, column in enumerate(df.columns):
    array_counts = Counter(df[column])
    x, y = [], []
    metki = ('', 'очень \nнеэффективно', 'достаточно \nнеэффективно', 'нейтрально', 'достаточно \nэффективно', 'очень \nэффективно', '')

    for key, value in array_counts.items():
        x.append(key);
        y.append(value)
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
    ax = plt.gca()
    patches = plt.bar(x, y, edgecolor='black', width=1.0)
    autolabel(ax.patches, height_factor=1.01)
    jet = plt.get_cmap('GnBu', len(patches))  # увета
    N = 7
    ind = np.arange(N)
    for i in range(len(patches)):
        patches[i].set_facecolor(jet(i))
   # plt.title("{}".format(str(column)))
    plt.title('\n'.join(wrap("{}".format(str(column)),60)))
    plt.xlim(0.1, 6)
    plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 10})
    plt.rc('axes', titlesize=10)
    plt.xticks(ind, metki, rotation=60)
    plt.tight_layout()
    ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines["bottom"].set_visible(True)
    ax.spines["left"].set_visible(True)
    # plt.axis('off')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну по идее `Counter` от самых больших значения перечисляет, можно в цикле раскраски на первой итерации цикла красный цвет забабахать попробовать.

Answer (score 0):

Если моя теория верна, что перечисление идёт от самых больших чисел и первый патч это тот, который нужен, то будет так:

```
for i in range(len(patches)):
    patches[i].set_facecolor(jet(i) if i > 0 else 'red')
```

Comment: Неа, кое-где красит в красный не самый высокий бар (как-то вразброс). Сейчас попытаюсь разобраться

Comment: @IoIo А `Counter` от больших к меньшим данные выдаёт, проверяли? Может конечно сами патчи потом перемешиваются, но вообще странно